# Question on friction

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction

[image]

Please look at the figure carefully. The question is written, and one has to match the two columns 1 and 2 given under "choices and explanation". Please tell me if I am really wrong, i.e. would you match C with both 1 and 3, or just 3. (my answer and the right answer is shown at the right hand side)

Thanks!

Comment: why the downvotes? Can anyone pls explain?

Comment: bcoz it's a no-effort HW question...that does not mean I have  downvoted

Comment: yaar, I did not ask for an answer. It is just for confirming if I havent gone horribly wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Yes you are correct!

it is a known bug in VMC answers. If you search their forums as well ,some 2 years old questions perhaps, you'll find this.

The friction is static and just opposes the external force. Hence the friction force is just $4.5N$, and body will remain at rest.

Comment: exactly! Thanks! But the saddest part is that it is a +6 -3 question, I have done it right, and still am getting -3!

Comment: @SaurabhRaje The point is not the marks in VMC. Also it's same for everyone. Just see you were right.

Comment: I didn't get the purpose of the link.

Comment: @SaurabhRaje: By ,mistake. wanted to give something else. NVM.

Comment: @user007, I would like to seek some guidance regarding what should be my strategy for the JEE exam. Can we discuss in a chat room or something?

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8936/books

Please join!

Comment: @SaurabhRaje: Hey I'm not any expert. Just appearing for JEE next sunday.So, what will I tell you?

Comment: well, you can tell me which books you used, and what did you do which you think was necessary, or maybe wrong!?